# The initial value problem

Tags: derivatives, initial-value-problems

I'm working on this question,

$$x' + x\tanh t = \sinh t, \quad x(0)= 3/2.$$

How I tried was

$$x' + x \tanh t = 0$$

$$x = C\tanh t \to x = C(t)\tanh t$$

Then derivative...
but I couldn't get until the end, am I doing it in wrong way? or did just I make a mistake?

Comment: A particular solution to your original equation (without initial value restriction) is $x=\dfrac{1}{2} \cosh t$, and your solution for the homogeneous equation is wrong. It should be $x=\dfrac{C}{\cosh t}$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $x=x(t)$. The problem is of the form $x' + P(t)x = Q(t)$. Such equations can be made exact with the integrating factor
$$\mu (t) = \exp\left (-\int P(t)dt\right ) $$
which then implies
$$ x = \frac{1}{\mu (t)} \left (\int \mu (t) Q(t) dt+C\right  ) $$

So, your main task would be to compute
$$\int \mu (t)\sinh t dt $$

---

Your approach works, too. Solve homogeneous eq. and couple with a particular solution  to the initial problem. You have

$$ x' + x \tanh t = 0 \Rightarrow \ln x = -\int \tanh tdt + C  $$